# Vaadin 7 - update textarea at value changed

Tags: java, refresh, vaadin, icepush

I'm new at vaadin and I want to display some infologs in a textarea. Currently I have set the pushmode in my CustomComponent to PushMode.AUTOMATIC ( @Push(PushMode.AUTOMATIC) ). But this works only the first time. To refresh the text I have to resize the window manual or click a button.
I found something called ICEPush but I do not understand this stuff :( and do not found good tutorials...

Has anybody a hint for me?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Which vaadin version are you using?
When you use Vaadin7 then you don't need ICEPush, this one is for Vaadin 6. Vaadin 7 has push already integrated

Comment: I use Vaadin 7. What I have to do to update view? Currently I have to do some action on screen to update...

Comment: Read this: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you made sure you changed the TextArea value using the ui.access method, and called the ui.push() method?

Kind of like this:

```
ui.access(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textArea.setValue(newValue);
        ui.push();
    }
});
```